Wavesurfer.js Show the wave of only a specific section of audio
I am using wavesurfer.js to display an audio waveform and that part works fine, but it shows the entire audio wave, whereas I need to pass a start point and end point or a start point and duration and only display that section in my #waveform.
Is this possible?  This is what I have tried, but again it shows the entire video/audio wave.
HTML:
<div id="waveform"></div>

JS:
//SHOW THE WAVEFORM ONLY FROM 10 SECONDS IN TO 20 SECONDS

var startPoint = 10;
var endPoint = 20;

    const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: container,
        waveColor: 'blue',
        progressColor: 'gray',
        height: 100,
        responsive: true,
        interact: false, // Prevent user interaction with the waveform
    });


    var videoSrc =  jQuery('#video-element').find('source').attr('src');
  
    wavesurfer.load(videoSrc);

    // When wavesurfer is ready, trim the audio to the specified section and visualize it
    wavesurfer.on('ready', function() {
    
      const duration = wavesurfer.getDuration();


      const segmentDuration = endPoint - startPoint;
      const zoomLevel = duration / segmentDuration;


      // Zoom to the specific section
      wavesurfer.zoom(zoomLevel);

      // Seek to the start point
      wavesurfer.seekTo(startPoint / duration);
  });

